# Dynamically adding column

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

Sometimes I need to add a column to an empty table

```
if (listfind(arguments.config[3], "payout"))    {
    QueryAddColumn(local.qryResult, "payout", "cf_sql_float");
    }
```

I get an error that looks like

[image]

It seems to want a `java.util.List`

Isn't `"cf_sql_float"` a single element list?

Comment: *Isn't "cf_sql_float" a single element list?* You are thinking of a CF list, which is basically a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  A `java.util.List` [translates to an Array in CF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7884.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7b7c.html) is your guide.  You need an array name.  I always use arrayNew().   This should do the trick.

```
QueryAddColumn(local.qryResult, "payout", "cf_sql_double", arrayNew(1));
```

Comment: Wow, the 3rd Parameter completely changes.

Comment: I had to change it to `"cf_sql_double"`

Comment: She was referring to my shoddy answer.  Oops.